# Successive operation on elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have

1. a list of four elements `{a, b, c, d}` and
2. a function `F` taking two arguments.

Is there a nice way to obtain `F[F[F[a, b], c], d]` ?

Comment: You want `Fold`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html

Comment: @Quantum_Oli You could post that as an answer. To close voters: I'm not sure this qualifies as "Simple to find in the documentation".  Imagine that you are new to Mathematica and don't even know if this functionality is included.  How would you search for it in the docs?  "Fold" is not the only standard name, many languages call it "reduce".  It's also not granted that one would come across `Fold` after reading some basic tutorials.  While this is a question about basic functionality, I think it's a reasonable question (for its level).

Comment: A starting point in the documentation would be the Wolfram Language Guide  [Applying Functions to Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html)

Comment: @Szabolcs - I think people associate "easy to answer" with the "simple mistake" closing option.  But I think that should be reserved for things like "You defined your function as `f[x]=` instead of `f[x_]=`" or "You aren't using the right number of arguments for that function".  A post like this serves to help future people that search google with "apply function to successive elements of a list mathematica" - like I usually search the web for the answer rather than search the docs.

Answer (score 6):

```
Fold[F, {a, b, c, d}]

(* out: F[F[F[a, b], c], d] *)
```

does the trick.

Comment: Many Thanks.Dan

Comment: @Lacour If the answer is sufficiently serving your needs, you may accept it.